# Can't receive the notification from googledrive while external user uploading file to a shared folder.

Tags: google-drive-api

I have 2 google drive accounts, one account its organization has subscribed notification for create, upload and edit activities is called as internal user by me. The other one without subscription is called as external user.

I set up these notifications by posting requests to https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/drive/watch?eventName=%event_name% to subscribe the hook for the events.

The internal user shared a folder to the external user. My web hook can receive notification while internal user uploading file to the shared folder. But it can't receive notification while the external user uploading file to the shared folder.

I would like to know this issue is caused by incorrect subscription or googledrive's original design?

Best,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

When sharing, try adding [Permissions: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert).

In your HTTP request,

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/permissions
```

add optional query parameter `sendNotificationEmails` with value set to `true` to send notification emails when sharing to users or groups. Note that this parameter is ignored and an email is sent if the role is owner.

See [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions) for more information.